# 404 error when using MailChimp API with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailchimp

I'm trying to integrate MailChimp API. I've switched out two different libraries and getting the same error.

```
[type] => http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/
[title] => Resource Not Found
[status] => 404
[detail] => The requested resource could not be found.
[instance] =>
```

Unfortunately this error doesn't provide me any usable information. The library I'm using is [this one](https://github.com/stef686/codeigniter-mailchimp-api-v3).

Here's the code I'm using in my controller:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(); 

    $this->load->library('mailchimp');
    $this->common = array(
        'list_id'   =>  '12345678',
    );
}

public function signup() {      

    $form = $this->input->post();

    if ( !empty($form['website']) ) {

        // If Honey Pot is filled out
        redirect('https://www.google.com');

    } else {

        $result = $this->mailchimp->call('POST', 
            'lists/'.$this->common['list_id'].'/members', 
            array(
                'email_address' =>  $form['email'], 
                'merge_fields'  =>  array( 
                        "FNAME" =>  $form['first_name'], 
                        "LNAME" =>  $form['last_name'] 
                    ), 
                'status'        =>  'subscribed',
            )
        );

        debug($result);
        return true;

        // Check Result
        if ( $result['status'] !== 'subscribed' && $result['status'] !== 'pending' ) {

            return false;

        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }       
}
```

The `debug` function is a helper I have that does a `print_r` wrapped in `<pre>` to make my life easier.

I'm hoping this is just a case of staring at the screen too long and missing the obvious or there's something amiss with the MailChimp API.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, I had the wrong API key and data center, their messaging should have been clearer. To avoid this mistake again I've written the following in my config file.

```
$config['api_key'] = '1276381263872163872163872-us11';
$data_center = explode("-", $config['api_key']);
$config['api_endpoint'] = 'https://'.$data_center[1].'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/';
```